# Pandas calculating order based on columns

Tags: python, pandas

Maybe it is not an appropriate title but let me explain my problem.

Following is my dataframe:

```
company manager_1 manager_2 manager_3 manager_4 manager_5 manager_6 _manager_7
Ford     AB         AC         AD       AE       AF       AG         AH
BMW      BA         BC         BD       BE       BF
FIAT     CA         CB         CD       CE       CF       CG
Mercedes BC         GA         GB
```

I need to convert these different columns into a single one and based on the order I want to create a additional column. What I need is basically this (I don't care about company names as it is just a toy example)

```
name  order
AB    7
AC    6
AD    5
AE    4
AF    3
AG    2
AH    1
BA    5
BC    4
BD    3
BE    2
BF    1
```

Actually, the manager_7 is the first manager of the company, so it takes to number 1 e.g. for AH, corresponding number is 1. 
I tried to transpose the columns, but couldn't get the output that I want. Any help?

Comment: There is a reverse order, he is the 5th manager of the company as it starts from BF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, we just need to do a descending count in each row.  We can get the row values in a more convenient order by stacking:

```
new = df.drop("company", 1).stack().to_frame("name")
new["order"] = new.groupby(level=0).cumcount(ascending=False) + 1
new = new.reset_index(drop=True)
```

gives me

```
In [65]: new
Out[65]: 
   name  order
0    AB      7
1    AC      6
2    AD      5
3    AE      4
4    AF      3
5    AG      2
6    AH      1
7    BA      5
8    BC      4
9    BD      3
10   BE      2
11   BF      1
12   CA      6
13   CB      5
14   CD      4
15   CE      3
16   CF      2
17   CG      1
18   BC      3
19   GA      2
20   GB      1
```

This assumes that the values you didn't show (e.g. manager_6/BMW) are actually null.  If they're the empty string instead, just add a `df = df.replace("", np.nan)` beforehand, or drop them manually after the `stack` step.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little bit artisanal manner.

```
df = df.drop(['Company'], axis=1)

for col in list(df):
    df[col] = df[col].fillna(0)

list_of_rows = []

def len_of_row_without_0(row):

    return len([non_zero_value for non_zero_value in row if non_zero_value != 0])

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    row_as_list = row.tolist()
    row_as_list = [(element, len_of_row_without_0(row_as_list) - row_as_list.index(element)) for element in row_as_list]
    list_of_rows = list_of_rows + row_as_list


data = [element for element in list_of_rows if element[0]!=0]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name', 'order'])
```

And it gives me the same result than DSM:

```
   name  order
0    AB      7
1    AC      6
2    AD      5
3    AE      4
4    AF      3
5    AG      2
6    AH      1
7    BA      5
8    BC      4
9    BD      3
10   BE      2
11   BF      1
12   CA      6
13   CB      5
14   CD      4
15   CE      3
16   CF      2
17   CG      1
18   BC      3
19   GA      2
20   GB      1
```